# Is there a way to use a lookup list inside a loop in GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an add to cart event that sends the cart to the Data Layer.  A cart item includes sku, quantity and price.  In GTM, I need to transform the sku into a product url and an image url.

I was hoping to use a lookup list, but I'm not sure if this is even possible, what would the input variable be if so?  Is my only option to create a javascript function that does this or can I utilize GTM variables somehow?

```
[{ 
   sku: "SU-LG",
   quantity: 1,
   price: 100.00},
 { 
   sku: "RS-SM",
   quantity: 1,
   price: 50.00}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably best done with a function as the lookup table is going to output a variable on that dataLayer.push, not a variable for each of the skus in an array.

You could use a JSON saved in a GTM variable, then reference the GTM variable in a function:

```
var array = [
 { 
   sku: "SU-LG",
   quantity: 1,
   price: 100.00
 },
 { 
   sku: "RS-SM",
   quantity: 1,
   price: 50.00
 }
]

var gtmJsonProduct = {
    "SU-LG": "su-lg-product.png",
    "RS-SM": "rs-sm-product.png"
};

var gtmJsonImage = {
    "SU-LG": "su-lg-image.png",
    "RS-SM": "rs-sm-image.png"
};

// Set these as a GTM variable instead?
// var gtmJsonProduct = {{gtmJsonProduct}};
// var gtmJsonImage = {{gtmJsonImage}};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var sku = array[i]['sku'];
  var productUrl = gtmJsonProduct[sku];
  var imageUrl = gtmJsonImage[sku];
  console.log(`product url for ${sku} = ${productUrl}`);
  console.log(`image url for ${sku} = ${imageUrl}`);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajsn/o9ykdz0g/)